# How can we perform headless testing for Protractor Testing in Jenkins or other CI integration tool?

Tags: continuous-integration, protractor, karma-runner, headless

I found out that it is not good to use PhantomJS to perform Protractor Testing , instead use Karma Testing. However I want to do end-to-end testing not unit testing.

End to End meaning I want to set commands which will make the browser acts like human user. Therefore I cannot switch back to Karma . I tried to use PhantomJS with Protractor as `browsername` but it doesn't seem work. If anyone can share knowledge on how to use PhantomJS and Protractor for Jenkins (CI) integration environment will be great help or any other headless browser you know of.

Comment: What version of protractor and phantomJS are you using?

Comment: @M.Hudson Protractor -> 5.1.2 and PhantomJS -> 2.1.1

Comment: You can use docker, full example: https://github.com/trion-development/angular-docker-jenkins

Answer (score 1):

Starting Chrome version 59, there is a [headless version of Chrome browser](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome). You can use this as your headless browser, and integrate it in your CI .

You can use the headless mode of Chrome, by just specifying `--headless` option in `chromeOptions` in the test capabilities like

```
 capabilities: {
browserName: 'chrome',
'chromeOptions': {
  args: ['--test-type','--headless']
}
```

Please note that there are bugs in this `headless` mode, so you need to careful about them too.

Comment: I found out something called XVNC plugin that can be used as headless server in Jenkins. Any idea on setting up this?